# Fast Jaro Winkler c++ code for numeric vectors

Tags: c++, jaro-winkler

Is there any library or the code of a function in C++ that I can use for comparing numeric vectors in C++?

Comment: What you mean by compare?

Also, what you mean by numeric vector?

Comment: What sort of vectors ?

Comment: Levenshtein distance wouldn't be a good option for me, because I have to compare the similarity regardless of the order of sequence

Comment: @PaulR C++ vectors that are filled with numbers

Comment: @khajvah I have many vectors that are filled with numbers like vector1->(12,42,13,65) and vector2->(12,42,13). Now I want to get the similarity between these two vectors.

Comment: I don't know anything about jaro-winkler but why don't you write your own function, I am guessing, it shouldn't be that hard

Comment: @khajvah I can write it down, but I am looking for a fast function that can do that. I have the Jaro_wrinkler Sudo code, but from what I got in Java, it wasn't fast enough

Answer (score 0):

Just googled a little and found smth like that [here](http://www.cppfrance.com/codes/DISTANCE-JARO-WINKLER_49753.aspx) I think you can use that to write your own which will work with numbers and vectors. Anyways, I dont know that topic but they say it is about strings(in other words letters). Also, I don't think for a project of this scale, speed will be an issue.

Comment: I have to do the measurement between 100000 vectors, so the speed is important for me. I will try this code to see how fast does it work.